# Call a function in a select element for filling ngOptions source?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, ng-options

I have a `<select>` as below:

```
<div ng-show="myCtrl.name == 'Jack'">
        <select ng-model="myCtrl.selectedValue" ng-options="value.id as value.title for value in myCtrl.valueDrpValues">
            <option value=""> Select One ...</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

And in `myController.js`, I have a function which should fill the  `myCtrl.valueDrpValues`. how can I call this function from the select tag? I tested the ng-init, but it didn't work. Also, I called the function exactly from the `ng-option` and it didn't work, too. (as below:)

```
ng-options="value.id as value.title for value in definitionCtrl.fillValueDrp()"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Call your function there and your array will be populated, for example like so:

```
<div ng-init="fillValueDrp()">
    <div ng-show="myCtrl.name == 'Jack'">
        <select ng-model="myCtrl.selectedValue" ng-options="value.id as value.title for value in myCtrl.valueDrpValues">
            <option value=""> Select One ...</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Elnaz was this helpful?

Comment: No it doesn't. I resolved it in other way (in ng-change of another -related- element -which causes to change the myCtrl.name value- I added an if condition to check the name and if condition result was true, the function is called.) But I couldn't resolve the problem with your and SSH's answer and don't know why. in debug mode the function wasn't call any more. I added an ; to end of ng-init and nothing happend to.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```js
var app = angular
  .module('MyApp', [
  ])
.controller('Main', ['$scope', function ($scope) { 
  var self = this;
  self.items = [];
  self.name = "Jack";
   
  self.fillValueDrp = function(){
     for(var i=0 ;i < 5; i++){
         self.items.push({"id":i,"title":i});
        }
    }

}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <div class="main-content" ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="Main as myCtrl">
      <div ng-show="myCtrl.name == 'Jack'" ng-init= "myCtrl.fillValueDrp()">
        <select ng-model="myCtrl.selectedValue "ng-options="value.id as value.title for value in myCtrl.items">
            <option value=""> Select One ...</option>
        </select>
</div>
    </div>
```